# Assigning string variable to another string

Tags: java, eclipse, android-2.2-froyo

I am new to android development, I have created a string variable with EditText ,how can i assign that string to another string.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you tried: `"="`? 
i.e.:-

```
String oldString = "odl Text";
String newString = oldString;
```

Simple steps can be:

1. get text from EditText as string
2. assign that to some other string variable.

---

Provide some more information to get better solutions. What problem are you facing?

Comment: actually i wanted the value of the string to be assigned to another string

Comment: @sameer: Whats the problem in that? Use `=` operator to do this.

Comment: here is my code                                              txtpassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Editpassword);           String strEditText;                         strEditText=txtpassword.text;                                   if(txtpassword==AdminPwdHandler.strCurrentPassword).            here strCurrentPassword is a string variable from another class

Comment: @sameer: do you get any error while running this?  see log cat to know if error comes or not.

Comment: ya i am getting the following  error.. incompatible operands EditText and String

Comment: @sameer:which? I can't see any in your comment.

Comment: @sameer: problem is you are comparing `txtpassword` which is editText with string [hoping that AdminPwdHandler.strCurrentPassword is string]. may be you need to compare `strEditText` with  `AdminPwdHandler.strCurrentPassword`. And also to compare string use `.equals()` and not `==`; i.e. this is right: `str.equals(str1)` and this is wrong: `str == str1`

Comment: ya that is the problem i am facing, i am not able to assign EditText value to String. i.e txtpassword to strEditText

Comment: @sameer: Use `getText()` method and then use `.toString()` on that like String `strEditText = txtpassword.getText().toString()`.

Comment: hey thank you very much its working.i have one more doubt ,how to print the value of variable on logcat like we use in C printf(" value is %s",stringvar);

Comment: `Log.i("Class","value is:"+stringvar);` see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) for more help.

Comment: @sameer: add this to your class: `import android.util.Log;`

Comment: I have another doubt ,I am not able to get the values from my string strCurrentPassword , which is a parsed string from a xml file.

Comment: what do you mean? I can't understand your doubt.

Comment: After parsing a xml file, i am storing the data into a string.that string i am not able to access in another class.

Comment: To access like this `AdminPwdHandler.strCurrentPassword` you need to declare `strCurrentPassword` as static in `AdminPedHandler` class.

Comment: ya i have declared it as static , but its still not working. can you please give some sample code

Comment: no i am not getting error, but the value of the string is showing null on logcat

Comment: ya i am asssigning it correctly. Can u please give some code that takes the string after parsing a xml file.

Comment: check value of string after getting it by parsing the xml. is it getting the value? See [here](http://www.ctctlabs.com/index.php/blog/detail/parsing_xml_on_android/) to know how to parse XML using SAX parser. Also see [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/)

Comment: hey i have a xml file   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NewDataSet>
<Password>abcd</Password>
</NewDataSet>, how to get the string from the above xml file

Answer (score 2):

```
String s1 = "..";
String s2 = s1;
```

In regard to `EditText` - its `getText()` method returns a `CharSequence`, that is not necessarily a `String`. You can use `.toString()` on it.